# TaskCompletionSource not working with more than one awaited Task - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c#, async-await, godot

I'm working on a game using the Godot game engine with Mono/C#.
I'm trying to achieve the following:

- Display a message on screen
- Wait for a mouse button click/screen tap
- Display another message
- Wait for click
- ...

Therefore I have a `Say()` method:

```cs
async Task Say(string msg)
{
  SetStatusText(msg);
  _tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Vector2>();
  await _tcs.Task;
  SetStatusText(string.Empty);
}
```

What I'm expecting is this to work:

```cs
async Task Foo()
{
  // Displays "First".
  await Say("First");
  // "Second" should be shown after a click.
  await Say("Second");
  // "Third" should be shown after another click.
  await Say("Third");
}
```

What actually happens is:

- "First" is shown
- "Second" is shown after a click.
- "Third" never shows up, even after a click.

I tracked it down to `_tcs` being `null` (or in an invalid state, if I don't set it to `null`) in my mouse button click code:

```cs
public void OnMouseButtonClicked(Vector2 mousePos)
{
  if(_tcs  != null)
  {
    _tcs.SetResult(mousePos);
    _tcs = null;
    return;
  }

  // Other code, executed if not using _tcs.
}
```

The mouse button click code sets the result of `_tcs` and this works fine for the first `await`, but then it fails, although I'm creating a new instance of `TaskCompletionSource` with every call of `Say()`.

Godot problem or has my C# async knowledge become so rusty that I'm missing something here? It almost feels as if `_tcs` is being captured and reused.

Comment: I suspect the problem is that when you call SetResult, you've then got two bits of code which are trying to set `_tcs` - the one in `OnMouseButtonClicked`, and the one in the next call to `Say()`. What order do you expect those to execute in? Which thread do you expect the continuation of `Foo` to execute in? (I don't know enough about Godot to know what it does in terms of threading and synchronization contexts.)

Comment: When you're saying there are two bits of code trying to access `_tcs` - wouldn't execution return to caller after each `await Say()` if the task isn't complete? I'll try to find out more about sync contexts. Assume, we were in a regular console app without sync context: should the code work as it is? @JonSkeet

Comment: No, in a regular console app the continuation would execute in a thread-pool thread, so there'd be a race condition between the two code paths (the continuation of `Foo` and the code in `OnMouseButtonClicked`). Execution of `Foo` can't "return to the caller" more than once - because the caller only makes the call once. The continuation is executed when the task is completed, and you need to plan for which thread that will happen on, and how it interacts with `OnMouseButtonClicked`.

Comment: Does this mean my use of `TaskCompletionSource` is wrong?

Comment: As I say, I don't know enough about Godot and how it handles synchronization contexts. But it certainly looks brittle to me in terms of the potential race condition.

Comment: Could you try passing `TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously` in the `TaskCompletionSource` constructor, and see if it makes any difference?

Comment: Also you haven't shown the `SetStatusText` method. Does it include any interaction with the `_tcs`?

Comment: Is `OnMouseButtonClicked` connected to a signal? Godot allows you to `await` signals directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> has my C# async knowledge become so rusty that I'm missing something here?

It's a tricky corner of `await`: continuations are scheduled synchronously. I describe this more [on my blog](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) and in [this single-threaded deadlock example](https://gist.github.com/StephenCleary/d5687f9d11947b7a8e3313c9fb2777bd).

The key takeaway is that `TaskCompletionSource<T>` will invoke continuations *before returning*, and this includes continuing methods that have `await`ed that task.

Walking through:

- `Foo` invokes `Say` the first time.
- `Say` awaits `_tcs.Task`, which is not complete, so it returns an incomplete task.
- `Foo` awaits the task returned from `Say`, and returns an incomplete task.
- The user clicks and `OnMouseButtonClicked` is invoked.
- `OnMouseButtonClicked` calls `_tcs.SetResult`. This not only completes the task, it also runs the task's continuations.
- This means that the remainder of the `Say` method is executed. If you place a breakpoint at `SetStatusText(string.Empty)`, you'll see that the thread stack has `OnMouseButtonClicked` and `SetResult` in it!
- At the end of the `Say` method, its task is completed, and *that* task's continuations are executed.
- This means `Foo` continues executing - from *within* `OnMouseButtonClicked`.
- `Foo` calls `Say` the second time, which sets `_tcs` and awaits the task. Since that task isn't complete, `Say` returns an incomplete task.
- `Foo` awaits that task, returning to `OnMouseButtonClicked`.
- `OnMouseButtonClicked` resumes executing after the `SetResult` line and sets `_tcs` to `null`.

This kind of [synchronous continuation doesn't always happen](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/when-executesynchronously-doesnt-execute-synchronously/), but it's annoying when it does. One simple workaround is to pass `TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously` to the `TaskCompletionSource<T>` constructor.

Comment: "The key takeaway is that TaskCompletionSource<T> will invoke continuations before returning,": Is this specific to TCS? How would I know when I'm potentially affected by this behavior?

Comment: That's how TCS works, and (by extension) how anything that uses TCS works. Including `await` continuations.

Answer (score 1):

Jon's comments made me reconsider the code and I ended up changing it.
Instead of one `TaskCompletionSource` I have now a queue:

```cs
Queue<TaskCompletionSource<Vector2>> _tcsQueue = new Queue<TaskCompletionSource<Vector2>>();
```

For every call to `Say()`, a new new `TaskComletionSource` is added:

```cs
async Task Say(string msg)
{
    SetStatusText(msg);
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Vector2>();
    _tcsQueue.Enqueue(tcs);
    await tcs.Task;
    SetStatusText(string.Empty);
}
```

In the click event handler I then dequeue the oldest TCS and set its result:

```cs
public void OnMouseButtonClicked(Vector2 mousePos)
{
    if(_tcsQueue.Count > 0)
    {
        var tcs = _tcsQueue.Dequeue();
        tcs.SetResult(mousePos);
        return;
    }
    // Other code.
}
```

This makes sure that for multiple calls to `Say()`, each click proceeds to the next.